# Function which calculates day hours - timesheet

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write 'simple' commandline based timesheet in python. What gives me problems is function which calculates shifts day hours. Tried that in excel, went to VBA and ended with python. I need them to calculate earnings later on. Shift is spread across day hours and night hours so night hours in the simplest version isn't a problem as total_hours - day_hours = night_hours
day_hours starts at 7 and finishes at 19
As shifts are irregular and can fall between and outside those hours eg. 6 - 20
where from 6 to 7 is another additional hours for night_hours and also from time to time shifts are spread across three different pay periods - days - x payrate, afternoons - y payrate, nights - z payrate. I may need a more complex function for that. I tried datetime module but problems occured when calculating wages.
At the momemt I'm stuck with- I would call infinite if else conditions. I'm not a student and I have very little experience in python.

Thanks

The more conditions I add the more uneffective it is

```
def day_hourss(start, finish):
    day_hourss = finish - start
    day_border = round((7 / 24), 5)
    night_border = round((19 / 24), 5)
    
    if finish < day_border and start > night_border:
        day_hourss = 0
    elif finish > day_border and start > night_border:
        day_hourss = finish - day_border
    elif finish > day_border and start < night_border and start > finish:
        day_hourss = (night_border - start) + (finish - day_border)
    elif finish < day_border and start < night_border:
        day_hourss = night_border - start
    elif finish > day_border and start < night_border and start < finish and start < day_border:
        day_hourss = finish - day_border   
                        
    return day_hourss * 24
```

Comment: This is a problem with logic, not programming. So you probably need to care about the logic. Start there. What are the work hour categories? Night - 6-7, day 7-19, or 19-20? What is afternoon? You should define the problem clearly first.

Comment: At the moment there is only day = 7-19, and night = 19-7. Let's say I go to work at 6 and finish at 20 so I will get paid for 12 day hours and 2 night hours. I haven't defined afternoons yet because I don't need it at the moment but it would be nice to do not change the whole function or even whole code  later if afternoons needed. Are you suggesting to write more independent conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:

```
#night hours 0-8
#day hours 8-18
#evening hours 18-24

def hours(start, finish):
    def to_minutes(x):
        hours, minutes = x.split(":")
        return int(hours)*60 + int(minutes)
    
    day_start = to_minutes("8:00") #480
    day_end = to_minutes("18:00") #1080
    start = to_minutes(start)
    finish = to_minutes(finish)  
    
    night = min(finish, day_start) - min(start,day_start)
    day = max(min(finish,day_end), day_start) - min(max(start, day_start), day_end)
    evening = max(finish, day_end) - max(start, day_end)
    
    #convert back to hours, but maybe leave decimal fractions for easier further calculations :
    night /= 60
    day /= 60
    evening /= 60
    
    print(f"Shift consisted of:\n\tNight hours:\t{night}\n\tDay hours:\t{day}\n\tEvening hours:\t{evening}") 
    return night, day, evening
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the calculation of day and night hours for your timesheet, you can use the datetime module to handle the time calculations more effectively.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def day_hourss(start, finish):
    day_border = time(7, 0)
    night_border = time(19, 0)

    start_time = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), start)
    finish_time = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), finish)

    if finish_time < start_time:
        finish_time += timedelta(days=1)

    # calculate the time within the day hours (7:00 to 19:00)
    day_hours = min(finish_time, datetime.combine(datetime.today(), night_border)) - max(start_time, datetime.combine(datetime.today(), day_border))
    
    night_hours = finish_time - start_time - day_hours
    return day_hours, night_hours


start_time = time(6, 0)
finish_time = time(20, 0)

day_hours, night_hours = day_hourss(start_time, finish_time)
print("Day Hours:", day_hours)      # Day Hours: 12:00:00
print("Night Hours:", night_hours)  # Night Hours: 2:00:00
```